# Connection to database not open?

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm currently working on a UWP app using the `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` namespace.

I can write data to the database and everything but when I want to delete the database I get an error saying `ExecuteNonQuery can only be called when the connection is open.`

I'm really new to using SQLite and databases in general so there are bound to be some errors. I just can't seem to find anything related to this error so I have to ask here.

This is the code I use to initialize the database:

```
public static void InitializeDatabase()
{
    using (SqliteConnection db =
        new SqliteConnection($"Filename=DashboardDatabase.db"))
    {
        db.Open();

        const string tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                                    "VisibilityTable (" +
                                    "ParameterId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
                                    "UserVisibility INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                                    "GeneralVisibility INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                                    "Format TEXT NOT NULL)";

        SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);

        try
        {
            createTable.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (SqliteException sqliteException)
        {
            Log.Logger.Error("An Error occurred while creating a table in the database:");
            Log.Logger.Error(sqliteException.Message);
        }

        db.Close();
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I use to drop the table and which creates the error es soon as it wants to run the `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

```
public static void DeleteTable()
{
    using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=DashboardDatabase.db"))
    {
        db.Open();

        SqliteCommand deleteCommand = new SqliteCommand("DROP TABLE VisibilityTable");

        deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        db.Close();
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate help in this situation.

**EDIT:**

As JayV pointed out in the comments I failed to add a part to my SqliteCommand...

So the solution was to change this line:

```
SqliteCommand deleteCommand = new SqliteCommand("DROP TABLE VisibilityTable");
```

to this:

```
SqliteCommand deleteCommand = new SqliteCommand("DROP TABLE VisibilityTable", db);
```

Comment: You don't seem to be setting the connection object to the newly created `deleteCommand` object. Try: SqliteCommand deleteCommand = new SqliteCommand("DROP TABLE VisibilityTable", db);

Comment: That was actually the problem...I just verified that by comparing closely to the other table I'm creating in another class and I seem to have forgotten that in all the methods of the VisibilityTable....Thank you very much for pointing that out :)

Comment: Please add an answer so people can find it easily.

Comment: I will wait for JayV to do that since he proposed the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `deleteCommand` object, you neglected to add the database connection to it.

Change the line:

```
SqliteCommand deleteCommand = new SqliteCommand("DROP TABLE VisibilityTable");
```

to:

```
SqliteCommand deleteCommand = new SqliteCommand("DROP TABLE VisibilityTable", db);
```

As an aside, you should consider wrapping the whole call in a `using(..)` block just like you did with the Connection.

Example:

```
using(SqliteCommand deleteCommand = new SqliteCommand("DROP TABLE VisibilityTable", db))
{
    deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```